# Why does Retrofit reponse.body().toString() not display the JSON from response?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm making a Retrofit call:

```
RetrofitInterfaces.IGetEvent service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetrofitInterfaces.IGetEvent.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = service.listRepos("1", "9e028aaa-d265-4e27-9528-30858ed8c13d");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: URL: " + response.raw().request().url());
                if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Error: " + t);
            }
        });
```

However it returns it the log as: `okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@fcf58e0`

But when I do

```
try {
   System.out.println(response.body().string());
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It returns me the JSON `{"server_time":1580949319,"event_info":[{"e_id":1`

Why does the first one not return the JSON String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the first one not return the JSON String?

Because you are calling `toString()`, whereas in your second snippet, you are calling `string()`. `string()` returns the JSON. `toString()`, in this case, returns the default implementation defined on the `Object` class, which is a mangled combination of the class name and the object ID.